# Azure Data Factory V2 logical OR

Tags: azure, api, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to create a logical OR for Azure Data Factory V2 pipeline activities? For example, we have two copy activities and on fails of any of its the Data Factory should call an API.

[image]

Comment: Hi IgorRogachov, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can.

You could add a [If Condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity) to create the logical pipeline. If the two copy active output status contains 'failed', then  call the API.

As we know, each copy active has the output has the bellow details:

```
"executionDetails": [
        {
            "source": {
                "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
                "region": "East US"
            },
            "sink": {
                "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
                "region": "East US"
            },
            "status": "Succeeded",
            "start": "2020-07-08T05:37:33.9079553Z",
            "duration": 4,
            "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 4,
            "usedParallelCopies": 1,
            "profile": {
                "queue": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 2
                },
                "transfer": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 1,
                    "details": {
                        "readingFromSource": {
                            "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
                            "workingDuration": 0,
                            "timeToFirstByte": 0
                        },
                        "writingToSink": {
                            "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
                            "workingDuration": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```

We can set the `executionDetails:{"status": "Succeeded"}` to the if-condition active:
[image]

Expression: No matter which actives failed, all the API:

```
@or(equals(activity('Copy data1').output.executionDetails.status,'Failed'),equals(activity('Copy data2').output.executionDetails.status,'Failed') )
```

If condition true, add the true active to call the API:
[image]

If all the copy actives are "succeeded"(condition false) and we don't want to do anything, we don't need to add the false active.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can please help me on this qus- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62942001/test-multiple-if-condition-in-azure-data-factory-and-string-equality-test-for-th

Comment: @Stark sure, I will try it and do my best!

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know about. When an activity has multiple conditions, they are treated as an AND condition, meaning that both copy activities have to fail to execute the web activity.

One common pattern to do this is create a pipeline that encapsulates the logic to report errors, and call it from each activity's failurem, capturing error output to a pipeline parameter.

Hope this helped!