# Test multiple If condition in Azure Data factory and string equality test for the activities

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to test a string value in Azure data factory.
Based on this String value my pipeline would get trigger.

I am collecting this value as a parameter from automation runbook.
If the parameter value is "Nike" then Nike pipeline will trigger and else some other pipeline.
The If condition having two options-

1. True Activity
2. False Activity

so if the parameter does not match with a specified value then my false block would get trigger.
But I have multiple values hence True/False condition will not suffice my requirement.

**So my first question is-** Can we test more than one condition in  ADF `If` condition activity so that whichever String value it matches that specific pipeline would get trigger, if not so then which activity should I use.

**My second question is-** How do I test the equality of parameter value so that I can trigger the specified pipeline.
below code I have tried but thrown the error.
`@equals(pipeline().parameters.clientName,'Nike')`
Please note- clientName is the parameter name

Comment: You need create so many pipelines which running under the condition``

Answer (score 0):

[image: 1]

Did you try "Switch" activity ?

See below link:
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/switch-activity-in-azure-data-factory-container-with-many-ifs

Comment: I didn't try the switch activity.

Comment: I guess this will solve your problem.  Use "Execute Pipeline" activity for each case